# What's the purpose of a dual two-pole breaker?

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, electrical-panel

I have one of these breakers in my panel? What is its purpose (vs a pair of two-pole breakers)? There are other [posts](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/110151/what-is-a-tandem-breaker-aka-duplex-cheater-twin-double-stuff-etc) that deal with tandem breakers but not specifically **dual** tandem breakers.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a quad breaker. The outer two are linked and the inner two are linked so that both pairs have 240 V across the connections. They are used to provide two 2-pole breakers, where a pair of ordinary 2-pole breakers would not work because the adjacent half slots are on the same leg.

If the available slots are such that the first pair of half slots are on different legs, then this quad breaker would not be used and would not fit. In that situation one would use a pair of ordinary compact 2-pole breakers.

Comment: So it's just a space-saver compared to two two-pole breakers?

Comment: Yes - that's correct. It allows two 240V breakers in the space of two 120V breakers

Comment: Edited answer. No, it would not be a space saver compared to a pair of half-width 2-pole breakers.  In a panel each *full* slot going down alternates between legs. An ordinary compact 2-pole breaker must be fitted *astride* two different full slots in order to get 240 V. If you try to fit an ordinary compact (half width) breaker in one slot it will not snap in--looks like it should fit but is designed to not fit. If you could force it in, there would be 0 V between the contacts because both are on the same leg.

Comment: But it's a space saver compared to 2 full sized 240V breaker pairs.

Comment: @JimStewart -- you're speaking in GE a bit too much with the first pair of half slots being on different legs, as that's a situation that can *only* occur on Q-line, not on any other 1" breaker line....

Comment: All my experience is with GE and I wrongly generalized. I gather that in other than GE panels *individual* 1/2 inch wide breakers are not available. Rather, the 1/2 in wide 1-pole breakers are in a joined pair called a "tandem" breaker, but they are separate 1-pole breakers.

Comment: @JimStewart -- you gather correctly indeed; for two-pole applications, *four* breaker poles are joined together in a 2" wide package to form a *quadruplex* breaker, which is what you see in the querent's picture